# Node.js - want 5 parallel calls to a method in a loop

Tags: node.js, express, async.js, kue

I have 1000 files of information in MongoDB collection. I am writing a query to fetch 1000 records and in a loop, I am calling a function to download that file to local system. So, it's a sequential process to download all 1000 files.

I want some parallelism in the downloading process. In the loop, I want to download 10 files at a time, meaning I want to call download function 10 times, after completing 10 file downloads I want to download next 10 files (that means I need to call download function 10 times).

How can I achieve this parallelism OR is there any better way to do this?

I saw `Kue` npm, but how to achieve this? By the way I am downloading from FTP, so I am using `basic-ftp` npm for ftp operations.

Comment: put some code here for at-least downloading one file

Answer (score 0):

The [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/v3/) library is very powerful for this, and quite easy too once you understand the basics.

I'd suggest that you use [eachLimit](http://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#eachLimit) so your app won't have to worry about looping through in batches of ten, it will just keep ten files downloading at the same time.

```
var files = ['a.txt', 'b.txt']
var concurrency = 10;

async.eachLimit(files, concurrency, downloadFile, onFinish);


function downloadFile(file, callback){

  // run your download code here
  // when file has downloaded, call callback(null)
  // if there is an error, call callback('error code')

}

function onFinish(err, results){

  if(err) {
    // do something with the error
  }

  // reaching this point means the files have all downloaded

}
```

The async library will run `downloadFile` in parallel, sending each instance an entry from the `files` list, then when every item in the list has completed it will call `onFinish`.

Comment: Thanks, @Graham. It's fairly simple. But nothing is returning from `results` in `onFinish` method. I want fileObject from `downloadFile`  method. When the download was success I am calling the callback like this `callback(null, file)`

Comment: `results` should be an array of files, if the function was called correctly.  Without seeing your code it's tough for me to know what's going on.

Comment: below is my code. `function downloadFile(file, callback){
  console.log(file);
  callback(null, file);
}
function onFinish(err, results){
  if(err) {
    console.log('error ', err);
  }
  console.log('completed ', results);
}` `results` always returns undefined. But in `downloadFile` file name fine.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your implementation I can only provide a generic answer.

Let's say that your download function receives one fileId and returns a promise that resolves when said file has finished downloading. For this POC, I will mock that up with a promise that will resolve to the file name after 200 to 500 ms.

```
function download(fileindex) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{ 
    setTimeout(()=>{ 
      resolve(`file_${fileindex}`);
    },200+300*Math.random());
  });
}
```

You have 1000 files and want to download them in 100 iterations of 10 files each.

let's encapsulate stuff. I'll declare a function that receives the starting ID and a size, and returns `[N...N+size]` ids

```
function* range(bucket, size=10) {
    let start = bucket*size, 
        end=start+size;
    for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
        yield i;
    }
}
```

You should create 100 "buckets" containing a reference to 10 files each.

```
 let buckets = [...range(0,100)].map(bucket=>{
    return [...range(bucket,10)];
 });
```

A this point, the contents of `buckets` are:

```
 [
   [file0 ... file9]
   ...
   [file 990 ... file 999]
 ]
```

Then, iterate over your buckets using `for..of`(which is async-capable)

On each iteration, use `Promise.all` to enqueue 10 calls to `download`

```
async function proceed() {
    for await(let bucket of buckets) { // for...of
       await Promise.all(bucket.reduce((accum,fileindex)=>{
           accum.push(download(fileindex)); 
           return accum; 
       },[]));
    }
}
```

let's see a running example (just 10 buckets, we're all busy here :D )

```js
function download(fileindex) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let file = `file_${fileindex}`;
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(file);
    }, 200 + 300 * Math.random());
  });
}

function* range(bucket, size = 10) {
  let start = bucket * size,
    end = start + size;
  for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
    yield i;
  }
}

let buckets = [...range(0, 10)].map(bucket => {
  return [...range(bucket, 10)];
});

async function proceed() {
  let bucketNumber = 0,
    timeStart = performance.now();
  for await (let bucket of buckets) {
    let startingTime = Number((performance.now() - timeStart) / 1000).toFixed(1).substr(-5),
      result = await Promise.all(bucket.reduce((accum, fileindex) => {
        accum.push(download(fileindex));
        return accum;
      }, []));
    console.log(
      `${startingTime}s downloading bucket ${bucketNumber}`
    );
    await result;
    let endingTime = Number((performance.now() - timeStart) / 1000).toFixed(1).substr(-5);

    console.log(
      `${endingTime}s bucket ${bucketNumber++} complete:`,
      `[${result[0]} ... ${result.pop()}]`
    );
  }
}

document.querySelector('#proceed').addEventListener('click',proceed);
```

```html
<button id="proceed" >Proceed</button>
```